# What is this Myanmar legume flour?

Tags: flour, food-identification, asian-cuisine, burmese-cuisine

What is this Myanmar legume flour? It reminded me of Chickpea flour in behavior but was clearly different, it might be Pigeon Pea flour. What is it actually?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SA! It might also help if you can show a picture of the flour, or describe why/how you got it.

Comment: Hello @FuzzyChef I finished all that flour ; I don't recognize how I got it matters to an answerer.

Comment: I don't know if this is what you've got, but one famous Myanmar dish is "tofu" made from chickpea flour. If this flour looks like chickpea flour, it's a good bet that's what it is.

Comment: @puertoportopoio Because knowing how you got it might rule some possibilities out or help give someone an idea of how to research the topic.

Comment: @dbmag9 For me, it feels like a waste of time.

Comment: @puertoportopoio You *really* wouldn't enjoy the information they ask you to give when you want something identified over at SciFi, then https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question  I hope you get what you're looking for.

Comment: Here it's a matter of someone who can read Burmese, as we all don't hopefully someone here can or can ask a relative.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be some kind of chickpea flour. According to [Google Translate](https://translate.google.ca/?sl=auto&tl=my&text=chickpea&op=translate), the Burmese word for chickpea is ကုလားပဲ, which matches the label. Here is a similar product, “roasted chickpea flour”, for label comparison [for sale](https://www.ninelife.ca/products/roasted-chickpea-powder-for-burmese-salads):

[image: Roasted chickpea powder]

Comment: Thanks, what you say feels true for me also because in the Burmese cuisine, it is common to roast and fry legumes, more than in any cuisine I have ever known. Thanks,

Comment: A similar flour is called sattu or saatu in South Asia.